# Need to run an application automatically in android box when it switched on

Tags: android

I developed a video streaming application in android and installed in android box. Now it works fine. But i need to open the android application automatically when android box switched on. Is there any way to do that? For any positive response thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` `Broadcastreceiver`, That will triggered automatically after your android box started.

Here is the example.

http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/07/bootcompleted-broadcastreceiver-in.html

This broadcast triggered when all android processes completed after boot.

Try this it will help.